# "Error: n() should only be called in a data context"

Tags: group-by, dplyr, spread

I am trying to spread my data from multiple lines to a more condensed dataset.

I have a dataset on bird nests and am trying to wrangle my data from having separate lines for juveniles and parents who have the same year and nest data entry.

Eg
Year      Nest     Sex    Ring_Number

2009      1        M      321

2009      1        F      189

2009      1        J      232

2009      1        J      101

I want my data to instead look like as follows:

Year      Nest     M_Ring_Number   F_Ring_Number   J_Ring_Number

2009      1        321             189             232

2009      1        321             189             101

Is anyone able to help me (I am new to using R)?

Thanks

CI<-C3  %>% group_by(Nest)%>% mutate(grouped_id=1:n())

Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. I sensed this function is being masked by another package. So I just detach all the packages and used only this package. It worked fine. You can also try any other package that provides this kind of function like margittr. Try your luck.